# Debug local WCF service with Basic Authentication always returns 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: c#, wcf, localhost, basic-authentication, iis-express

I have a problem accessing a .Net WCF Service that uses Basic authentication. The server's web.config file has the service configured as such:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="api.GlobalService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="Basic" contract="api.IGlobalService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

with the binding:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Basic">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
```

In my IIS Express config file I enabled basic authentication as such:

```
<basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
```

I am running it in debug mode, on localhost, and I don't want a custom basic authentication, I want it to authenticate against Windows credentials. I access the server directly, from the browser, and enter my windows credentials when prompted, or from Postman using basic authentication and credentials, however I always get a 401. I am not authorized to access a server I run on my own machine with my own credentials. Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, in the application that consumes the WCF Service

```
WCFServiececlient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
WCFServiececlient.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```